# Firestore rules to allow query on the document ID and another field

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am having troubles writing Firestore rules to securely allow fetching a document by its ID and an additional field. Let's consider that I want to fetch the user with the ID `USER_ID` only if his `deletionDate` is null.

I wrote the following security rule:

```
/users/{userId} {
  allow read: if resource.data.deletionDate == null;
}
```

My query with the JS client:

```js
await db.collection('users')
    .where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', 'USER_ID')
    .where('deletionDate', '==', null)
    .limit(1)
    .get();
```

It appears that this is not handled as a query on a collection. But rather like a document fetched by its ID. The Firestore simulator throws the following exception for non existing docs:

> Variable read error. Variable: [resource]. for 'list'

Changing the security rule to `resource == null || resource.data.deletionDate == null` does not help. The thing is, I would prefer to receive an empty result if the document cannot be fetched because of absent / with `deletionDate`. I don't want mute the permission exception received by the clients. So I can monitor potential misconfigurations.

I noticed that the following query does exactly what I want:

```js
await db.collection('users')
    .where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '!=', 'FAKE_ID')
    .where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', 'USER_ID')
    .where('deletionDate', '==', null)
    .limit(1)
    .get();
```

But this looks too hacky to be used in production.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: It could be an error with simulator

Comment: @pepe I gave it a try, the real Firestore has the same behavior.